# Unity 5 Distributed Physics in Client Server Model

Tags: c#, physics, networking, unity, distribution

I have a server which controls a physics object via buttons, adding force whenever I click them. I want to be able to have a client connect and whenever the physics object has a reaction on the server, the same reaction occurs on the client. But I don't want the client to do any physics calculations. I tried this out as seen below. When a button on the server is hit and the object moves, an RPC is sent to the client with the position, rotation and velocity of the server physics object and then applied to the object on the client.

```
[ClientRpc]
void RpcSendPhysicsInfo(Vector2 Pos, float Rot, Vector2 Velo)
{
    Debug.Log ("Received");
    moveableBarrel.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().position = Pos;
    moveableBarrel.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().rotation = Rot;
    moveableBarrel.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = Velo;
}

void OnGUI()
{

    if (isServer) 
    {

        if (GUI.Button (new Rect(0,Screen.height/3, 150, 30),"Move Barrel Right")) 
        {
            moveableBarrel.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(50, 0));
            //RpcSendPhysicsInfo(physics info)
            RpcSendPhysicsInfo(moveableBarrel.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position, moveableBarrel.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().rotation, 
                               moveableBarrel.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity); 
        }
```

With this code, whenever the server side button is hit nothing happens on the client side. But when it is hit again the client object moves to the position of the server object, but the speed the object is moving isn't the same as the server object. Obviously this didn't give the reaction that I wanted which was to have the client object copy the server object and in the long run make it seem as though the client carried out the physics when actually it was the server. Is there more data to send? Have I sent the wrong data? Have I went about it all wrong?